# Proving a series bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

> If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ is a uniformly and absolutely convergent series with $f_n(x)$ continuous for all $n$ and for all $x\in [0,1]$ such that for sufficiently large $N$, $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|f_n(x)|$ is bounded. Then prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ is bounded.

Since we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} f_n(x)+\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}f_n(x)$

How to use the uniform and absolute convergence given in question?

Comment: Without any information about the set to which x belongs the statement is false as you can see from $x \in (0,1/2)$, $f_1(x)=1/x$ and $f_n(x)=x^n$, $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @LucaGoldoniPh.D. Thanks. What extra conditions do we need so that the sum is bounded?

Comment: @LucaGoldoniPh.D. Actually $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: What if you took $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $f_k\equiv 0$ for all $k\geq 2$?

Comment: @MatthewH. I have edited my question. Actually all the $f_n(x)$ are continuous.

Comment: The function $f_1(x)=1/x$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and you can take, as already pointed out by @Mattew H, $f_k\equiv 0$. Still the statement is false. I think you need a compact set as well as continuous functions.

Comment: @LucaGoldoniPh.D. Yes my set is compact. It is $[0,1]$.

Comment: @LucaGoldoniPh.D. Also my functions are continuous in the compact interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Use uniform convergence to find $N$ so that $n\geq N$ implies $$\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)\Bigg|<1$$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Next, for each $1\leq k \leq N$, find $M_k$ so that $|f_k(x)|\leq M_k$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. These values of $M_k$ are guaranteed to exist by the extreme value theorem. Put $M=1+\sum_{k=1}^N M_k$. Show for any $x\in [0,1]$ that $\Big|\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)\Big|<M$.